# Excel - when I open new workbook it recalculates currently opened

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use Excel a lot. I have one big workbook with many sheets open almost all the time. Recalculating it takes around half a minute. That's OK, but the problem is that when I open some other file it seems to be calculating this one big workbook even if I don't care about it now at all and I just want to see something else, like a few kilobytes big CSV with no formulas in it! Yes I have calculation set to manual and still it recalculates this workbook which I didn't touch for like half an hour. It does not happen always though. I am working with other CSVs or XLSXs and from time to time Excel decides to recalculate that big one and slows everything down which is annoying especially when I am on a meeting and people await my answer to some question.

Comment: Perhaps not a good answer but a dirty hack to get around the problem. Make all formulas static and use VBA to update the workbook instead. That means you need to code cell A1 in vba to become `range("A1").value = range("B1").value+range("C1").value` and the workbook will only update when you run the macro.

Answer (score 1):

I normally do this : Windows > Run : Excel > load the big workbook.

|| then I do did again.. for the 2nd (small) workbook. ..

|| It seems that running different instance of excel for different file helps in term of (system) stability..

|| Eg.. if the 1st excel instance hangs, it won't interrupt the other one..

Comment: That sounds good, I will test it! Isn't there some options related to instances of excel maybe?

Comment: maybe a [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=to+open+excel+as+a+different+instance..&t=ffab&ia=web) will help..

Comment: sorry but these tricks no longer seem to work - when I run new excel, it is there as a second process for a second but then disappears as it merges with the current one. The only way seems to be run it as another user (administrator for example). I see that registry tweak on MS web, but I don't want all the workbooks to have a new instance as it would use too much RAM probably.

Comment: sorry.. that's all I got.. dare to type it coz had used the tricks before.. Or maybe my excel file is not as heavy.. Or the new excel/windows versions react differently.. Or.. I'm just plain getting old.. :Þ

Answer (score 1):

https://excelgorilla.com/excel/general/open-multiple-instances-excel/
Seems like last version of Excel works with this command line parameter

```
excel /x
```

holding ALT and clicking in start menu on excel did not work for me.
In my case I made a shortcut with this in target to open a specific file

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /x "C:\Users\VitezslavZurek\desktop\MyWorkbook.xlsx"
```

this opens new process excel.exe and it should be independent from the others.